# How to improve performance when using GIF's as background in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am currently programming a game for which i use GIF backgrounds to have an universal dynamic theme in the menu's of the game. When i started using the GIF backgrounds my scene switching turned very slow (1-2 seconds wait-time before the next scene shows when a button is clicked). I have no idea how to improve the performance since i really want to hold on to the GIF's I'm using. I already tried:

```
    setCache(true);
    setCacheShape(true);
    setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
```

But it's not doing the trick for me.

The code which i use to implement these gif's in my BorderPane:

```
this.setId("home");
```

In my CSS Stylesheet:

```
#home{
-fx-background-image: url("/be/kdg/stylesheet/versie3.gif");
-fx-background-repeat:stretch;
-fx-background-size:  110%  100%;
-fx-background-position: bottom ;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I tried both animating them myself and loading the cache in the class manually but still no improvement in performance.

Comment: Considered using a [loading cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) and set the background image manually instead of using css?

Comment: I suspect that the indivudual frames of the GIF are either not drawing using acceleration or are recreated as textures every time.  Try turning the GIF into a sequence of images and animating them yourself.